# Is there a workaround for testing criteria based sharing rules?

Tags: apex, unit-test, sharing

From the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rule_types.htm&type=5), you cannot directly test criteria based sharing rules.

I'm just thinking about if there is a work around for this limitation - possibly by creating __share records in test context, though not sure how I would be able to take the sharing criteria and apply that logically in code, as would want to do this dynamically to ensure that if the sharing rule criteria changed, that my test code would still run.

What have other people done to test criteria based sharing rules?

Comment: Out of interest, why would you need this? The test classes are typically run when someone deploys a change set/package, and the Modify All Data permission is needed for this, meaning that the sharing rules will always be overlooked when the test is run. If the test is aimed to run ad-hoc to verify correctness, you could achieve this by logging in as the user you want to test the access for, and try to open the relevant records

Comment: We have a complex org with a number of sharing rules across different objects. We'd want to us .runAs() within tests to set the running user to different users where the sharing rules apply differently, e.g run as user A who can see records, run as user B who cannot see records. We need this to ensure our sharing rules, that we have for our industries compliance rules, are working. Doing it manually takes a long time!

Comment: @developer__c follow sfdcfox's answer.